# Sending context variables in Django ssi template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

Seeing as the django ssi template tag only accepts absolute paths and the absolute path to a file is going to be different in different environments, I am trying to send in the absolute path as a variable from the view but it doesn't seem to be working.

in the view I have

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
template_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'templates/frontend/scroll.html')

def function_name(request):
   ...
   return render_to_response(template, {... 'template_dir': template_dir,} ,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

and in the template file with the ssi tag I have:

```
{% ssi {{ template_dir }} parsed %}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not just use [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) instead of `ssi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to include a template in your project arborescence. You can do that with the [`include` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include), which takes in parameter a template available in your project.
So if your `templates` directory is in your `TEMPLATES_DIR` tuple setting, you can do:

```
 {% include "frontend/scroll.html" %}
```

This may not be the response *expected*, but it's the ideal solution in your case.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize that the include tag parsed the content. Aside from the absolute path requirement, is there any difference between {% ssi $path parsed %} and {% include $path %}?

Comment: From the outside, both methods does the same thing, but I keep a preference for the `include` which avoid security holes and is more logic (append a subtemplate from the project than appending a random template for an absolute path)